# Apparent inconsistency in ASP.NET MVC routing behaviour

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Given the controller below

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        return RedirectToRoute(new { action = "Index" });
    }

}
```

And this routing

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Route1",
        "Route1",
        new {controller = "Account", action = "Index"});

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );

}
```

When I browse to My/Test then MyController's Test Action is hit as expected. Then the `RedirectToRoute` result uses Route1 as I have specified the Action as "Index". And as I didn't specify a Controller it defaults to "Account". This hits the AccountController's Index Action as expected

If I change the routing to the code below then it works differently and not as I expect. When I browse to My/Test then this redirects to MyController's Index Action and not HomeController's Index Action.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

I know when `RedirectToAction` is used then MVC will infer the current Controller so this would redirect to MyController's Index Action but code comments in the MVC source says `RedirectToRoute` doesn't infer the current Controller and I have hopefully proved this with the 1st example.

Anybody have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Not the answer, but for future reference (in case you haven't heard of it) this is a great tool: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Comment: Is it me ging code blind at the end of the day or is the changed code the same as the original one? or did you mean that you are erasing the "Route1" mapping?

Comment: @JTMon Correct, I just erased the "Route1" mapping

Comment: @Ecnalyr I use Glimpse which has a route debugging component inspired by Phil's, it is indeed a great tool!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current request values are **always** used. The difference between `Url.Action` and `Url.RouteUrl` (which is used by `RedirectToRoute`) is that `Url.Action` overrides null values for `controller` and `action` with the current request values (which are never null in MVC), and `Url.RouteUrl` does not (it leaves them null). Note that a null value is not the same as a non-existent, ommited or undefined value.

Check out [this post](http://maxtoroq.blogspot.com/2012/04/putting-aspnet-routing-to-test.html) I wrote about routing:

> The UrlHelper.Action set of methods take actionName and controllerName
>   string parameters. Calling these methods can be translated to
>   something equivalent to `Url.RouteUrl(new { action = actionName,
>   controller = controllerName })`. As we verified earlier in *Cannot use
>   null or empty string for default value without parameter*, using null
>   for actionName and/or controllerName can result in failing to match
>   the desired route. For this reason Url.Action uses the current request
>   controller and action values whenever null is used for actionName
>   and/or controllerName.

---

To clarify, the first example matches Route1 because:

1. The route doesn't have tokens, which means it doesn't require values to match.
2. The value for action matches the default value.
3. The code doesn't provide a value for controller. If a value had been provided it would need to be "Account" to match.

On the second example My is used as value for controller, taken from the current request values because the route contains a controller token and a value is not provided.

Comment: My/Test URL returns a RedirectToRoute that only contains an Action however

Comment: Sorry shall try to explain a bit better... The Test Action in MyController does a redirect and only specifies the Action. As I have not specified the Controller I would expect it to use "Home" as the Controller as specified in the route defaults

Comment: You say RedirectToRoute uses Url.Route which **does not** override null values with the current request values. My example uses RedirectToRoute and from what I can see, **it is** overriding the "controller" route value with the current request controller

Comment: @DavidWilliams By value overriding I mean the values that you provide, not the route's default values.

Comment: Sorry still not following. From my question and your answer my understanding is this, I call `RedirectToRoute(new { action = "Index"})`, so I am not providing a controller (so I presume it is null). You say that `RedirectToRoute` **doesn't** override null values with the current request controller/action. So I expect the route's default controller value of "Home" to be used but it is not

Comment: @DavidWilliams First, focus on the first sentence of my answer, that explains why `RedirectToRoute(new { action = "Index" })` uses My and not Home controller. About the diference between `Url.Action` and `Url.RouteUrl`, not providing a value is not the same as providing a null value.

Comment: Starting to understand now, however with this new understanding my 1st scenario doesn't behave as I would expect. As I don't provide a controller it should infer "My" as the controller causing it to match the "Default" route, however it matches the "Route1" route

Comment: @DavidWilliams The current request values are not used to match routes, only to provide values for parameters that you don't provide yourself. Because Route1 doesn't have parameters (tokens), it matches.

Comment: @DavidWilliams Strictly speaking, the current request values can affect route matching (e.g. if you have a constraint for that value), but they are not used unless needed (e.g. a value is required and you didn't provide it).

Comment: I see, makes sense. What you said in your last comment is what I'm looking for, how do I set the controller in the "Route1" route to be required? I want to match that route only if **both** controller and action are specified

Comment: @DavidWilliams Instead of changing the route use `Url.Action` and `RedirectToAction` instead, as these always include values for controller and action, and they will have to be "Account" and "Index" to match Route1.

Comment: That would work for the dummy project in the question but in my project due to its architecture I am unable to, I wish I could! The `ActionResult` you want to return is done in a "Handler" class that doesn't inherit the Controller class so `RedirectToAction` isn't available. Is the only way to specify the controller in `RedirectToRoute`? Not an ideal solution as it could easily be forgotten about but might be my only option

Comment: @DavidWilliams Yes, with `Url.RouteUrl` you need to explicitly specify the controller you want to match.

Comment: Thanks for all your help you are a credit to the community. I'd like to mark your post as the answer but in its current state it doesn't fully answer my question. If you could edit it to something along these lines, if you agree with what I say of course

Comment: First example with "Route1" doesn't imply the current controller because there isn't a {controller} token in the route. Second example without "Route1" does imply the current controller because there is a {controller} token making it a required value, therefore RedirectToRoute will use the current controller. The best solution is to use RedirectToAction as this will always infer the current controller

Comment: My question was just looking for an explanation but I think it will be worth mentioning `RedirectToAction` as this may help others

Comment: Made a small edit just to make your last point more clear. If it's ok I'll mark it as the answer

Comment: @DavidWilliams Your edit is confusing, because the route has a default value for controller, which makes controller optional.

Comment: Sorry you're correct, it is a bit confusing. How about now? I just wanted to make it clear that it is using the request value because a controller token exists in the route. Feel free to edit it so it makes more sense

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14872/discussion-between-david-williams-and-max-toro)